# Unable to translate any text with element type "errorMessage" in Azure B2C

Tags: translation, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

While working on my Signup and Signin page with azure B2C, I noticed some texts weren't being translated to the language that I customized so I proceeded to translate them manually. Most of them were translated succesfully except for the error messages.

No matter what I try, only the texts with type element "errorMessage" are the ones who don't get translated and I don't really know why.

This is my code to translate the texts manually:

```
      <BuildingBlocks>    
        <ContentDefinitions>
                <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
                    <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
                        <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.signuporsignin.en"/>
                        <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="es" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.signuporsignin.es"/>
                        <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="ca" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.signuporsignin.ca"/>
                        <!-- Add more languages here -->
                    </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
                </ContentDefinition>
                <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountsignup">
                    <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
                        <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="es" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.localaccountsignup.es"/>
                        <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="ca" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.localaccountsignup.ca"/>
                        <!-- Add more languages here -->
                    </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
                </ContentDefinition>
                <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountpasswordreset">
                    <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
                        <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="es" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.localaccountpasswordreset.es"/>
                        <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="ca" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.localaccountpasswordreset.ca"/>
                        <!-- Add more languages here -->
                    </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
                </ContentDefinition>
            </ContentDefinitions>
        <Localization Enabled="true">
          <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en" MergeBehavior="Append">
            <SupportedLanguage>en</SupportedLanguage>
                <SupportedLanguage>es</SupportedLanguage>
                <SupportedLanguage>ca</SupportedLanguage>
          </SupportedLanguages>
          <LocalizedResources Id="api.signuporsignin.en">
                <LocalizedStrings>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="local_intro_generic">Sign in</LocalizedString>
                </LocalizedStrings>
            </LocalizedResources>
          <LocalizedResources Id="api.signuporsignin.es">
                <LocalizedStrings>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="DefaultMessage">Usuario o contraseña incorrectos.</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="signInName" StringId="DisplayName">Correo Electrónico</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="password" StringId="DisplayName">Contraseña</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="local_intro_generic">Iniciar sesión</LocalizedString>
                </LocalizedStrings>
            </LocalizedResources>
            <LocalizedResources Id="api.signuporsignin.ca">
                <LocalizedStrings>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="DefaultMessage">Usuari o contrasenya incorrectes.</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="signInName" StringId="DisplayName">Adreça electrònica</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="password" StringId="DisplayName">Contrasenya</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="local_intro_generic">Iniciar sessió</LocalizedString>
                </LocalizedStrings>
            </LocalizedResources>
            <LocalizedResources Id="api.localaccountsignup.es">
                <LocalizedStrings>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="email" StringId="DisplayName">Correo Electrónico</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="newPassword" StringId="DisplayName">Nueva Contraseña</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="newPassword" StringId="PatternHelpText">8-16 caracteres, que contengan 3 de los 4 siguientes: Minúsculas, mayúsculas, números (0-9),y uno o más de los símbolos siguientes: @ # $ % ^ &amp; * - _ + = [ ] { } | \ : ' , ? / ` ~ " ( ) ; .</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="reenterPassword" StringId="DisplayName">Confirmar Nueva Contraseña</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="reenterPassword" StringId="PatternHelpText">8-16 caracteres, que contengan 3 de los 4 siguientes: Minúsculas, mayúsculas, números (0-9),y uno o más de los símbolos siguientes: @ # $ % ^ &amp; * - _ + = [ ] { } | \ : ' , ? / ` ~ " ( ) ; .</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="surname" StringId="DisplayName">Apellido</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="givenName" StringId="DisplayName">Nombre</LocalizedString>
                </LocalizedStrings>
            </LocalizedResources>
            <LocalizedResources Id="api.localaccountsignup.ca">
                <LocalizedStrings>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="email" StringId="DisplayName">Adreça electrònica</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="newPassword" StringId="DisplayName">Nova Contrasenya</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="newPassword" StringId="PatternHelpText">8-16 caràcters, que continguin 3 dels 4 símbols següents: Minúscules, majúscules, números (0-9), i un o més caràcters dels següents símbols: @ # $ % ^ &amp; * - _ + = [ ] { } | \ : ' , ? / ` ~ " ( ) ; .</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="reenterPassword" StringId="DisplayName">Confirmar Nova Contrasenya</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="reenterPassword" StringId="PatternHelpText">8-16 caràcters, que continguin 3 dels 4 símbols següents: Minúscules, majúscules, números (0-9), i un o més caràcters dels següents símbols: @ # $ % ^ &amp; * - _ + = [ ] { } | \ : ' , ? / ` ~ " ( ) ; .</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="surname" StringId="DisplayName">Cognom</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="givenName" StringId="DisplayName">Nom</LocalizedString>
                </LocalizedStrings>
            </LocalizedResources>
            <LocalizedResources Id="api.localaccountpasswordreset.es">
                <LocalizedStrings>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="email" StringId="DisplayName">Correo Electrónico</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="newPassword" StringId="DisplayName">Nueva Contraseña</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="newPassword" StringId="PatternHelpText">8-16 caracteres, que contengan 3 de los 4 siguientes: Minúsculas, mayúsculas, números (0-9),y uno o más de los símbolos siguientes: @ # $ % ^ &amp; * - _ + = [ ] { } | \ : ' , ? / ` ~ " ( ) ; .</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="reenterPassword" StringId="DisplayName">Confirmar Nueva Contraseña</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="reenterPassword" StringId="PatternHelpText">8-16 caracteres, que contengan 3 de los 4 siguientes: Minúsculas, mayúsculas, números (0-9),y uno o más de los símbolos siguientes: @ # $ % ^ &amp; * - _ + = [ ] { } | \ : ' , ? / ` ~ " ( ) ; .</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">Ya existe un usuario con el ID especificado. Por favor, elija uno diferente.</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExist">No se pudo encontrar un usuario con la credencial especificada.</LocalizedString>
                </LocalizedStrings>
            </LocalizedResources>
            <LocalizedResources Id="api.localaccountpasswordreset.ca">
                <LocalizedStrings>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="email" StringId="DisplayName">Adreça electrònica</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="newPassword" StringId="DisplayName">Nova Contrasenya</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="newPassword" StringId="PatternHelpText">8-16 caràcters, que continguin 3 dels 4 símbols següents: Minúscules, majúscules, números (0-9), i un o més caràcters dels següents símbols: @ # $ % ^ &amp; * - _ + = [ ] { } | \ : ' , ? / ` ~ " ( ) ; .</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="reenterPassword" StringId="DisplayName">Confirmar Nova Contrasenya</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="reenterPassword" StringId="PatternHelpText">8-16 caràcters, que continguin 3 dels 4 símbols següents: Minúscules, majúscules, números (0-9), i un o més caràcters dels següents símbols: @ # $ % ^ &amp; * - _ + = [ ] { } | \ : ' , ? / ` ~ " ( ) ; .</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">Ja existeix un usuari amb la ID especificada. Si us plau, trieu-ne un de diferent.</LocalizedString>
                    <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExist">No s'ha pogut trobar un usuari amb la credencial especificada.</LocalizedString>
                </LocalizedStrings>
            </LocalizedResources>
```

And those are the versions I'm using i my policy:

```
<ContentDefinitions>
            <!-- This content definition is to render an error page that displays unhandled errors. -->
            <ContentDefinition Id="api.error">
                <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/exception.cshtml</LoadUri>
                <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
                <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:globalexception:1.2.1</DataUri>
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="DisplayName">Error page</Item>
                </Metadata>
            </ContentDefinition>
            <ContentDefinition Id="api.idpselections">
                <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/idpSelector.cshtml</LoadUri>
                <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
                <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:providerselection:1.2.1</DataUri>
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="DisplayName">Idp selection page</Item>
                    <Item Key="language.intro">Sign in</Item>
                </Metadata>
            </ContentDefinition>
            <ContentDefinition Id="api.idpselections.signup">
                <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/idpSelector.cshtml</LoadUri>
                <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
                <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:providerselection:1.2.1</DataUri>
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="DisplayName">Idp selection page</Item>
                    <Item Key="language.intro">Sign up</Item>
                </Metadata>
            </ContentDefinition>
            <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
                <LoadUri></LoadUri>
                <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
                <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:unifiedssp:2.1.5</DataUri>
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="DisplayName">Signin and Signup</Item>
                </Metadata>
            </ContentDefinition>
            <ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted">
                <LoadUri></LoadUri>
                <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
                <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.8</DataUri>
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="DisplayName">Collect information from user page</Item>
                </Metadata>
            </ContentDefinition>
            <ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted.profileupdate">
                <LoadUri></LoadUri>
                <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
                <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.8</DataUri>
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="DisplayName">Collect information from user page</Item>
                </Metadata>
            </ContentDefinition>
            <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountsignup">
                <LoadUri></LoadUri>
                <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
                <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.7</DataUri>
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="DisplayName">Local account sign up page</Item>
                </Metadata>
            </ContentDefinition>
            <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountpasswordreset">
                <LoadUri></LoadUri>
                <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
                <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.7</DataUri>
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="DisplayName">Local account change password page</Item>
                </Metadata>
            </ContentDefinition>
            <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountsignin">
                <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml</LoadUri>
                <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
                <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.7</DataUri>
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="DisplayName">Collect information from user page</Item>
                </Metadata>
            </ContentDefinition>
        </ContentDefinitions>
```

And as you can see, only the error messages aren't being translated, the other texts that I translated manually are just working fine:

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFdRT.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZepJ.png)

Edit: I'm also trying to translate to French, Italian, Deutch and Portuguese following the same procedure as shown above with same results: the texts with element type "errorMessage": they aren't being translated.

Anyone knows why this is happening?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/language-customization?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#provide-language-specific-labels) , Azure AD B2C doesn’t support Catalan(ca) language which can seen in the below screen shot:

[image]

Comment: FYI as this is really a documentation question, you could have just shared the link, as a comment, and closed the question (it's off-topic as written - it's about language support). No need to post snippets from Microsoft docs. Also no need to request that people accept your answer, *especially* right after posting an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! But unfortunately, although you are right, I am also trying to translate those error messages to French, Italian, Deutch, Portuguese and Spanish and I find myself unable to translate the error messages. Also in the images I provided I show the correct translations to Spanish, except for the error messages who aren't being translated. Again, thank you for you answer, as I didn't realise Catalan isn't a language supported for the user flow in B2C.